# Magic the gathering welcome pack favorable color distribution

Tags: probability

I was wondering if there is a simple way to get this problem.

In magic the gathering there are five colors, { Red, White, Blue, Black, Geeen}. In a welcome deck you get to pick one of the five colors, the deck has both that color and a randomly chosen color that is different from it. If I get one pack from each color what is the probability that It evens out and I get two of each color as opposed to some other arrangement?

I have the total sample space as being 4^5 total outcomes

If it were total random For each color instead I would have 5^5 total outcomes and would be able to use the easy combination of 5! Total outcomes being the way you can arrange the 5 individual colors. Therefore having 5!/5^5 in the easier example

Comment: I think this is a stars and bars problem. $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 = 5$ where the $x_i$'s can be zero. So the probability is one divided by $9$ choose $5$ or one in $126$. What do you think?

Comment: Stars and bars is almost applicable, **however** it isn't because of the fact that there isn't $5$ choices for the second color of each pack. There are only $4$ choices for each, and the four choices are dependent upon which color deck you chose, as the second color is a "randomly chosen color that is different from it".

Comment: @WaveX ahhh that makes sense. Thanks for pointing that out for me!

Comment: In practice, the distribution of colors in a case of welcome packs isn’t truly random. The cards are packed by cycling through some long fixed sequence.

Comment: What long fixed sequence is that?

Comment: Stars and bars looks interesting; how would the number of solutions change if they had to be ordered; say x1>x2>x3>x4>x5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The desired outcome is a [derangement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement) of $(r,w,u,b,g)$, thus there are $44$ ways to get one of each color from the randomly chosen colors.
$$\frac{44}{1024}=4.296875\%$$